# Former2 not showing Event Source Mappings of AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to generate the cloudformation of an already existing AWS Lambda. This lambda has destinations and asynchronous invocation enabled. But in former2 it is not showing anything under Event Source Mappings and Event Invoke Configs tabs. Has anyone faced this same issue and knows how to resolve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was a [bug](https://github.com/iann0036/former2/commit/31623536c1de5d3fc3ed0523b042ab446e97ea05) in the datatable cleanup for that specific resource type.

Should be fixed now.